# Laravel 4 restful controller GET parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In order to add parameter to a GET method, I know that I have to add `{parameter}` in the route like the following

```
Route::get('example/search/{id}', 'ExampleController@exampleMethod')
```

However, is there a way to do this using the RESTful controller like the following?

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('example', 'ExampleController')
```

**ExampleController.php**

```
public function getSearch($id){
    //do something with $id
}
```

The above doesn't work because the `routes.php` doesn't expect a parameter to `getSearch` method. I wonder if there is a way to solve this without having to add individual `Route::get` routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

// ExampleController.php

class ExampleController extends BaseController {
    public function getSearch($id = null){
        if ($id == null) {
            return 'no id';
        }
        return $id;
    }
}

// routes.php

Route::controller('example', 'ExampleController');

?>
```

`php artisan routes`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great. But what about same situation with the "index" method in Laravel 4? Even if you define it as `public function getIndex($id = null)`, requesting URL `domain.tld/example/1` throws `Controller method not found` error. You have to define a seperate route for that, like 
`Route::get('example/{id}', ['uses' => 'ExampleController@getIndex'])->where('id', '[0-9]+');`. 

**NOTE**: this route decralation should take place BEFORE your Route::controller declaration to work.

Comment: @vitalikaz Index has a very specific use. It is supposed to be the index page in your application. Therefore it is not supposed to take parameters by design as far as I understand so what you are doing is overriding the desired default behavior.